# Multithread proccesing events from epoll_wait with coroutines

Tags: c++, coroutine, epoll, c++-coroutine

I have such io context class:

```
    class IOContext
    {
    public:
        explicit IOContext(uint32_t eventPoolCount);
        ~IOContext();

        IOContext(IOContext&) = delete;
        IOContext& operator=(IOContext&) = delete;
        IOContext(IOContext&&) = delete;
        IOContext& operator=(IOContext&&) = delete;

        void processAwaitingEvents(int timeout);

        void scheduleOperation(std::derived_from<IOOperation> auto& operation)
        {
            // ok?
            if(0 == epoll_ctl(this->epollFD, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, operation.fd, &operation.settings))
                return;

            if(errno == EEXIST)
                // re-init event
                if(0 == epoll_ctl(this->epollFD, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, operation.fd, &operation.settings))
                    return;

            throw std::system_error{errno, std::system_category(), strerror(errno)};
        }

    private:
        tinycoro::Generator<IOOperation::CoroHandle> yieldAwaitingEvents(int timeout);

        std::unique_ptr<epoll_event[]> eventsList;
        const uint32_t eventPoolCount;
        int epollFD = -1;
    };
```

```
    //.
    //. //constructor, destructor
    //.
    void IOContext::processAwaitingEvents(int timeout)
    {
        for(auto& event : this->yieldAwaitingEvents(timeout))
        {
            event.resume();
        }
    }

    tinycoro::Generator<IOOperation::CoroHandle> IOContext::yieldAwaitingEvents(int timeout)
    {
        int eventCount = epoll_wait(this->epollFD, eventsList.get(), this->eventPoolCount, timeout);
        if(eventCount == -1)
        {
            throw std::system_error{errno, std::system_category(), strerror(errno)};
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < eventCount; ++i)
        {
            co_yield std::coroutine_handle<IOOperation>::from_address(eventsList[i].data.ptr);
        }
    }
```

and I want to enable multi-threaded processing for io events (IOOperation is the base class, which contains fd), so when some events are ready, first from N thread will get them and process them.
So, I think that i could move eventsList to cpp as thread_local variable, like this:

```
    //.
    //. //constructor, destructor
    //.
    void IOContext::processAwaitingEvents(int timeout)
    {
        for(auto& event : this->yieldAwaitingEvents(timeout))
        {
            event.resume();
        }
    }

    tinycoro::Generator<IOOperation::CoroHandle> IOContext::yieldAwaitingEvents(int timeout)
    {
        thread_local std::unique_ptr<epoll_event[]> eventsList = std::make_unique<epoll_event[]>(this->eventPollCount);
        int eventCount = epoll_wait(this->epollFD, eventsList.get(), this->eventPoolCount, timeout);
        if(eventCount == -1)
        {
            throw std::system_error{errno, std::system_category(), strerror(errno)};
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < eventCount; ++i)
        {
            co_yield std::coroutine_handle<IOOperation>::from_address(eventsList[i].data.ptr);
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure it's good idea, ie if this solution is safe (I do some tests, everything was OK, but despite this, I have doubts).
I could make yieldAwaitingEvents as a public function, but I don't think that giving raw coroutine handle is good idea...
Thanks!

EDIT:
I change a little bit code - initializing of thread_local variable was moved to yieldAwaitingEvents function

Comment: So you want to have multiple threads, all calling `epoll_wait` on the same fd, right? And you're relying on them each reading no more than 12 events for load balancing? This should be fine, but events aren't necessarily going to be evenly distributed across threads.

Comment: @Useless Yes, exactly. It doesn't have to be 12 (its hardcoded for example) events for one call, but yes.
Of course, I also take into account that it does not have to be evenly.

Another idea is to return the coroutin handle from yieldAwaitingEvents, then I could distribute out more evenly - but in that case I provide the user with the resume () function, which I don't want to do.